# dataBinding in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android

I'm a new in this but this time my Android Studio 3.0 (The lastest version) doesn't create the class ActivityMainBinding for reasons that I don't know. I follow the guide: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html
I add the property

```
dataBinding.enabled = true
```

To the file build.grandle and sync my project and in MainActivity.java I can't create a instance type of MainActivityBinding because it doesn't exist. My file's name is activity_main.xml and thus

```
MainActivityBinding binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
```

gave a error "Cannot resolve symbol MainActivityBinding"

Comment: I use this: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'}

Answer (score 2):

DataBinding class will be generated based on your xml file name. It is clearly mentioned in doc https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html.

By default, a Binding class will be generated based on the name of the layout file, converting it to Pascal case and suffixing “Binding” to it. The above layout file was main_activity.xml so the generate class was MainActivityBinding

If your xml name is activity_main.xml than DataBinding class name will be ActivityMainBinding.

If your xml name is main_activity.xml than DataBinding class name will be MainActivityBinding.

Comment: I know! but it doesn't work. When I write "Binding" the IDE show the following: Binding, BindingAdapter, BindingBuildInfo, BindingConversion, BindingMethod, Binding Methods and ViewDataBinding. The first and the last ones are classes.

Comment: did you add <layout> tag to the xml ? the right name of binding should be MainActivityBinding as Hanza said

Comment: Please. Tell me the version of you Gradle Plugin. Maybe you need update your gradle.properties file to include the following line:  android.databinding.enableV2=true

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

Answer (score 1):

I fixed with the following:
1.- To the file activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- I Added this lines
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 <layout>-->
```

2.- Remove

```
dataBinding.enabled = true
```

and sync your project and add it again, sync it with this that class will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Generated classes become available in compile time. Please follow:

1. Build -> Clean
2. Build -> Make Project

After these steps you are able to import generated packages

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this feature in your `build.gradle`:

```
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding true
}
```

If your class name is `MainActivity` then:

```java
ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

else if name is `ActivityMain` then:

```java
MainActivityBinding binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```